# Implementing printf without va_list

Tags: c

In the last programming homework, we were supposed to implement a printf without using va_list. I could not get mine working. Here was my attempt:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdarg.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int myprintf( const char * format, ... )
{
void *traverse = &format;
traverse += sizeof(char*);
int i,j;
char k;
char * str; 


for (i = 0; i < strlen(format); i++) 
{
     if (format[i] == '%') 
     {
              switch (format[i+1]) 
                {
                    case 's':
                      str = *( (char**)traverse  );
                      for (j = 0; j < strlen(str); j++) 
                        {
                            k = str[j];
                            putchar(k);
                        }
                    traverse += sizeof(char*);
                    break;

                 case 'd':
                    j = *( (int*)traverse );
                    putchar(j); 
                    traverse += sizeof(int*);
                    break;

                case 'c':
                        k = *( (char*)traverse );
                        putchar(k);
                        traverse += sizeof(char*);
                        break;

                 case '%' :
                      putchar('%');
                      break;
                }

          i++;

         }

    else 
    {
      putchar(format[i]);
    }
}
}



int main()
{
char k = 'a';
int g = 6;
myprintf("Hello, this is %d How are You", 6);

 }
```

The output was 'Hello, this is  How are You' and the int 6 was not printed as I expected it would be. Any idea what is wrong with the code? Thanks!

Comment: "what is wring with the code?" --> Code needs to use `va_list` for portable functional code.  The assumptions this code makes to operate correctly are, at best,  implementation defined and at worst undefined behavior.

Comment: Not the actual problem, but after `%d` why advance by size of a pointer, not size of an `int`? An `int` was passed, not a pointer. Similarly after `%c`but the additonal pitfall is that `char` is promoted to `int` in calls to `printf`.

Comment: Assuming this isn't meant to be portable... what platform?  32-bit?  64-bit?

Comment: I am working on a raspberry pi 3. I was assuming that the stack contained pointers to all the arguments, that's why I was advancing by the size of a pointer to an int

Comment: `traverse += sizeof(char*);` you cannot add to a void pointer.

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour. Without knowing the ABI and possibly reverting to compiler extensions, intrinsics or assembly, there is no way - that's why `stdarg.h` has to be provided by **any** implementation! Your teacher most likely has ancient implementations in mind which indeed passed variable arguments on the stack. This is often not true for modern ABIs.

Comment: Tip: try coding using `va_list` and related macros first.  Then move to `va_list`-less.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize what several people have alluded to:

`printf` takes a variable-length argument list.  To access these arguments, you need to know the mechanics of how arguments are passed to functions.  The C spec makes a point to avoid declaring how low-level things like this should work; it will differ from one platform to another.  Instead, the C standard mandated that all of this platform-specific stuff be wrapped up behind a standardized interface, and called it `stdarg.h`.

This means there are two possible results here.  Either your instructor wants you to conclude that it can't be done in standard C and have a deeper understanding as to why `stdarg.h` exists, or they want you to do something extremely platform-specific.  If the latter, then this isn't a C question (you'll be invoking lots of undefined behavior and going *way* outside the language spec), it's a question about your platform's low-level interface.  You'll need to explain more about your processor architecture and ABI version before we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are sure that the arguments would be at the stack, without alignments and the stack has the correct direction, your code has issues.

1. C has a call by value semantic. I.e., for `int` and `char` the value itself is at the stack, not a pointer. Thus, the increments of `traverse` are incorrect in the cases for format letter 'd' and 'c'.
2. In case of 'd', you fetch the integer argument and interpret it as `char`. However, you have to convert it to a string and output the string's characters.